# How to resolve Namespace and data models name collisions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a project built with ASP.NET webforms that used ADO.NET to communicate with the database. I recently transformed all the model classes using Entity Data Model Wizard. It created the model classes with same table names as in the database. Now I want to create API controllers but the problem is that I can't use these model classes as I have the namespaces with the same name as the tables so I get an error when I compile the code. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: You have a "Class" and "Namespace" with the same name?

Comment: Apparently yes. Like I have a video folder that has all the classes inside it with the name space "video" and I have the same model class with the name "video". Asp.net is not letting me have both.

Comment: You can show the line that the error occurs? And the error description!?

Comment: I just recompiled the code and the errors disappeared :/